Elasticsearch tokenizer, analizer with own pattern
How to write own analyser that would be use in search when searching keyword would be in following pattern
The string of characters always starts with the letters "RTP" followed by a space or a dash, another string of characters of any combination and length, and then another space or a dash, and another string of characters of any combination and length.
so the search phrase can have values ​​like these, for example.
RTP-458-8D9A
RTP-599RT-7

Currently when I search using "match" operator. Elasticseach split this word by a dash and in results I receive lots of incorrect documents containing one of any splitted word.

Does the field that you want to search contain only values in this format of this is something that may appear in the larger strings that you want to treat as a single token?

They may appear in large string but this RTP-458-8D9A i wan to treat as a single token.

I think the simplest way would be to detect such tokens in a char filter and convert them into something that would be split into tokens afterwards. Here is one example of how you can achieve that:
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "rtp_converter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "RTP[\\- ]([A-Z0-9]+)[\\- ]([A-Z0-9]+)",
          "replacement": "RTP_$1_$2"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rtp_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "rtp_converter"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "rtp_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "rtp_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}


POST test/_analyze
{
  "text": "This is RTP-458-8D9A and RTP 599RT 7.",
  "analyzer": "rtp_analyzer"
}


POST test/_bulk?refresh=true
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{ "rtp_text": "This is RTP-458-8D9A and RTP 599RT 7."}
{ "index": { "_id": "2" } }
{ "rtp_text": "This will not be found even though it contains 458 8D9A 599RT 7 and rtp."}


POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "rtp_text": "RTP-458-8D9A"
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "rtp_text": "RTP-599RT-7"
    }
  }
}


Thx. I will try use it.
